# In Sublime Text 2 Build Output is Funky Characters

Tags: formatting, sublimetext2

For example, when I run a build with:

```
{
    "cmd": ["grunt"]
}
```

I get bash formatting output in the console. Is there a way to either display the formatting or remove the formatting characters?

```
[4mRunning "lint:files" (lint) task[24m...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with ST2. Here is the official feature request:

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/55640-htmlansi-in-output/

Answer (score 5):

The output looks much better if you pass the no-color flag:

```
{
  "cmd": ["grunt", "--no-color"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, jmconrad, but I'm looking for a Sublime Text fix that gets uses colors or at least doesn't render the formatting characters. There are other commands I'd like to run that don't have a 'no-color' option.